# How to work with the list which the elements are different shapes of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine different shapes of data frame which are the elements of a python list. since concatenate only for same shape data frame, I am thinking to sort the list first so that I got same shaped data frame together . And then I subset the list to small list and combine them.

I have tried using `pd.append`, `pd.concat` and looping through the list. but the results are combined horizontally.

Questions I have are :

How to use sort the list and subset it?

Am I on the right track to do it ?  what are other ways to do it ?

For example :
dataframe1 is the `list[0]`.

```
name    age    year
john     20     3
mike     22     4
```

dataframe2 is the `list[1]`

```
name age
james 25
logan 27
```

dataframe3 is the `list[2]`

```
name  age  year  class
ali    24   5     1
beck   23   3     3
```

Ideal outcome is just stack all of them together vertically

this what I did.  the example above is just simplified problem I have

```
import PyPDF2
import tabula
import pandas as pd

df=tabula.read_pdf("Report 04.01.2019 to 03.31.2020.pdf",  stream=True ,pages='1-3', multiple_tables='True')

df_f=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):
    
    df_f=pd.concat([df_f,df[i]],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: It's hard to answer that question because we don't know how the PDF is being read. Can you send the print(df) result. import PyPDF2 import tabula import pandas as pd df=tabula.read_pdf("Report 04.01.2019 to 03.31.2020.pdf", stream=True ,pages='1-3', multiple_tables='True') print(df)

Comment: @Alexandre, the data frames are like my examples, some of them have three columns some of them have two.  I have tried using the DataFrame.shape  to distinguish them . But , I still got some of them combined horizontally.

Comment: The example with `concat()` doesn't work? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I figure it out. First to get all the dataframe have same columns count together. and then use concat().